# Session handling in nodejs. CORS issue

Tags: ajax, node.js, cookies, express, cors

I know there's plenty of questions asked regarding this issue, but I've been researching my problem for a while now, and none of the suggested solutions seem to solve my problem.

I am developing a web application.

In the frontend I'm throwing AJAX petitions to a backend, developed in nodejs.

In the backend I'm trying to handle the user session with the express.js middleware.

I can't make the session work.

I think It's an issue with the AJAX petitions, but from what I've read, I should be able to create cookies with such petitions, so I don't know what to think.

In my backend I'm using a middleware to deal with CORS issues. Here's the code:

```
var enableCORS = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Cookie');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      res.status(200).send('');
    }
    else {
      next();
    }
};


app.use(enableCORS);
```

Then, I'm trying to handle the session like this when I handle the actual petition:

```
req.session.field = 'value';
```

The problem is, I don't receive any session info in the following petitions.

I've been looking at the issue closely. One example of AJAX petition that I'm using would be this one:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/resource',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr){ xhr.withCredentials = true; },
            success: function(x, status, xhr){
              console.log(x);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){ }
          });
```

I've been watching the http package exchange in the network section of my browser. These are the request and response headers:

Request Headers:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:29
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.net
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://example.net/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, Cookie
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:96
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 12 Apr 2015 16:32:36 GMT
Server:Cowboy
Set-Cookie:connect.sid=s%3A7OCuaEWUjkpdOrxFuNo6KrtpnS_e5SpZ.S2O4PIVy2YkKuLxQ9KuzfcaszRZzqq5hjL3PfaHrQBw; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 12 Apr 2015 17:22:36 GMT
Vary:X-HTTP-Method-Override
Via:1.1 vegur
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
```

In the response the Set-Cookie header is actually sent, but no cookie is created in my browser, and so the following petitions will not carry that information with them.

I'm sure it's some stupid detail, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried multiple browsers?

Comment: How would that help? Currently I'm using google chrome, version 39.0.2171.71

Comment: It looks like your issue arrises from the browser you are using not honoring the set-cookie response header.  [Here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=158148) is a link with someone reporting the same issue for chrome 39 on OSX 10.10.1.  Maybe try with some different browsers and see if things work for any of them?

Comment: I just tried it out in firefox, and i get the same result. Any ideas? Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an alternative, so I'm answering my own question.

First of all, from what I've read, there's no way of doing what I want to do with cookies.

So, in order to handle the session while being able to implement cors with a wildcard I finally went with JWT (JSON web tokens).

Here's an article with an explanation and a nice example: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/

Thanks to everybody who tried to help me out here.

Comment: i came out same problem. But i need to implement a message code verify function which i need to store my msg code in session, but i can't get anything i store in req.session. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Yeah, with this implementation (enabling CORS, etc) you won't be able to use cookies, and so your session info won't be stored and you'll lose it. With JWT you can encode whichever information you consider vital for your user's session and decode it in every petition. Hope this helps!